# android device not getting data from local server

Tags: android, mysql, httpconnection

When testing my android app on an emulator I can get data from my local MySQL server database using an httpconnection.  However, when testing the app on my samsung phone, I cannot get data from my database.  Is there some parameter I need in my manifest file or does anyone know what I need to do to be able to get data from my local server onto my samsung phone?

Comment: Which error did You get while running on the second device?

Comment: @Dave Any log messages regarding this issue? Because your question is too far to know where it goes wrong. I had made it worked on my device many times before. Do you have separate internet connection to your phone?

Comment: are you using localhost to send the data to android and are you in the same network?

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you can't access the local database from device.

If you want to access on device you should host your database online and internet should be connected to access that url and then you can probably access it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I guess I will have to test against my internet database which is fine as long as know I can't do it from a local database using my phone.